# LXC strorage directory

Tags: lxc

I am trying to change my lxc storage directory from `/var/lib/lxc` to something else like `/var/directory1`

I added the line:

```
lxc.lxcpath=/var/directory1
```

in the lxc configuration file in `/etc/lxc/lxc.conf`, but nothing changes.

Does anybody have an Idea about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`man lxc-create` says :

```
-P, --lxcpath=PATH
          Use an alternate container path. The default is /var/lib/lxc.
```

Did you try this ?